# How write a .gitignore file which can work on specify platform

Tags: git, ignore, platform

I am developing a Qt project which can work on both mac and windows platform, in the project, there is a .gitignore file, now I want to ignore some files on windows platform, and ignore the other files on mac, is there a syntax which like :

```
macx{
    // ignore mac files
}

win{
    //ignore windows files
}
```

in the .gitignore file?
thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no support for conditional behaviour in `.gitignore`. Most likely it would be okay to just add rules for ignoring both the mac files and the windows files. Ie. the mac rules will be there, but have no effect on the windows system (and vice versa).

Comment: Normally, you should create one `.gitignore` for project and it should be platform agnostic. If you want to separate them for clarity, you can use comments. On the other hand, platform specific `.gitignore` is not good practice.